# DataGridViewComboBox Value is not valid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

### Background

I'm trying to set a column on my DGV up as a combobox. I've added all the columns to the gridview in the designer so all that is left is to bind them to the dataset.

The datatype of the Status column is varchar.

### Question

However i keep getting a very unhelpful error message at run time. Am i doing something wrong?

> DataGridViewComboBox Value is not valid.

The above error happens when setting the datasource of the dgv.

```
  dataGridView1.DataSource = JoblistDataSet.Tables["Joblist"];
```

### My Code

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Column = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns["Status"];
Column.DataPropertyName = "Status";

DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Status"];

cbCell.Items.Add("New");
cbCell.Items.Add("Hold");
cbCell.Items.Add("Remove");

dataGridView1.DataSource = JoblistDataSet.Tables["Joblist"];
```

Comment: What is the `DataType` of your table "JobList", column "Status"?

Comment: @GrantWinney added the offending line in the question.

Comment: @IvanStoev datatype Varchar.

Comment: `JoblistDataSet.Tables["Joblist"].Columns["Status"].DataType` cannot be "varchar". The question was if it's a `string`, `int` etc. From your answer looks like it's a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are populating [DataGridViewComboBoxCell.Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.items(v=vs.110).aspx) for row index 0 instead of [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.items(v=vs.110).aspx) which applies for **all** rows (hope you noticed `Cell` vs `Column`).

Use something like this instead

```
var statusColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns["Status"];
statusColumn.DataPropertyName = "Status";
statusColumn.Items.Add("New");
statusColumn.Items.Add("Hold");
statusColumn.Items.Add("Remove");
// ...
```